# Odd yellow electrical connector (GM)

Tags: electrical, gmc, jimmy

I'm trying to pull an instrument panel in a 2000 GM Jimmy. There is this odd electrical connector I've never seen before. I can't squeeze the retention ramp to disconnect the thing. It has an odd orange wedge inside. Anybody know how to disconnect this thing?  Anybody know why it's designed this way?[image: yellow connection]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That orange thing is a lock. Pull it straight out and you can depress the tab. You see those and other style locks a lot on GMs.

Comment: On most vehicles, bright yellow indicates an SRS relationship. Since this had a lock on it, I'd highly suggest this is the case.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Yellow vehicle wiring, by regulation, denotes an SRS circuit. They usually have double lock connector.

Comment: @Paulster2 Abbreviations? SRS?   Hmm, as I think about this,we would all be better communicators with the new guys if we just quit using abbreviations without defining them first... so I'll go fix my goof... General Motors (GM)...

Comment: SRS=Safety Restraint system (i.e. airbag).